# What actually happens when using foreach/WhenAll?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

From the threading point of view, what happens in this code?

```
public static Task ForEach<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, Task> process) {
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var item in items) {
        tasks.Add(process(item));
    }
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Are all tasks scheduled to run in parallel or can some execute sequentially?
Would there be problems (aside from memory usage) if the collection is large?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are all tasks scheduled to run in parallel or can some execute sequentially?
>   Would there be problems (aside from memory usage) if the collection is large?

There is no way to answer that question in general, because it depends on the kind of `Task` that is returned by `process`. **A `Task` is not a thread**; it's just something that represents an operation with a mechanism to be notified when the operation completes. Some tasks are implemented using threads (e.g. when you use `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`), but others are not (e.g. tasks created with `TaskCompletionSource<T>`).

Now, assuming that in your case, `process` returns tasks that run in a thread. Again, it depends how the task was scheduled. Typically, if you use `Task.Run`, or `Task.Factory.StartNew` with the default creation options, it will use a thread from the `ThreadPool`. So if you create more tasks than the maximum number of threads in the pool, they will be queued until threads become available.

So, several tasks will run in parallel, but not all of them; it depends on the maximum number of threads in the `ThreadPool`.